# Python requests user agent not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests to get the html page.

I am using the latest version of chrome in the user agent.

But the response tells that `Please update your browser`.

Here is my sample code.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.choicehotels.com/alabama/mobile/quality-inn-hotels/al045/hotel-reviews/4'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36', 'content-type': 'application/xhtml+xml', 'referer': url}
url_response = s.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=15)
print url_response.text
```

I am using python 2.7 in a windows server.

But when I ran the same code in my local I got the required output.

Answer (score 0):

`Please update your browser` is the answer.

You cannot do https with old browser (and request in python2.7 could be old browser). There were a lot of security problems in https protocols, so it seems that servers doesn't allow to connect with unsecure encryptions and connection standards.